# Flask SQLAlchemy query returns a querystring instead of an actual resultselt

Tags: python-3.x, flask-sqlalchemy

I have used flask-sqlalchemy to create a mixin in a file called `itemAbstract.py`, to be shared by two model classes: `ItemModel` and `ItemHistoryModel`respectively. Below is the code I have written in the itemAbstract.py

```
from databaseHandler import databaseHandler
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declared_attr

# pylint: disable=maybe-no-member

class Item(databaseHandler.Model):
    __abstract__ = True

    itemName = databaseHandler.Column(databaseHandler.String(80), nullable = False)

    price = databaseHandler.Column(databaseHandler.Numeric, nullable = False)

    itemImage = databaseHandler.Column(databaseHandler.String(1000), nullable = False)

    @classmethod
    @declared_attr
    def restaurantId(cls):
        return databaseHandler.Column(
            databaseHandler.Integer, databaseHandler.ForeignKey("restaurant.restaurantId"))

    @classmethod
    @declared_attr
    def restaurant(cls):
        return databaseHandler.relationship(
            "RestaurantModel", backref=databaseHandler.backref('items', lazy=True))

    @classmethod
    @declared_attr
    def productTypeId(cls):
        return databaseHandler.Column(
            databaseHandler.Integer, databaseHandler.ForeignKey("product_type.productTypeId"))

    @classmethod
    @declared_attr
    def productType(cls): 
        return databaseHandler.relationship(
            "ProductTypeModel", backref=databaseHandler.backref('items', lazy=True))
```

And I have inherited it in the `itemModel.py` and `itemHistoryModel.py` like so:

```
from databaseHandler import databaseHandler
from sqlalchemy import and_, or_
from abstracts.itemAbstract import Item

# pylint: disable=maybe-no-member

class ItemModel(Item):

    __tablename__ = 'item'

    itemId = databaseHandler.Column(databaseHandler.Integer, primary_key = True)
```

And

```
from databaseHandler import databaseHandler
from sqlalchemy import and_, or_
from abstracts.itemAbstract import Item


# pylint: disable=maybe-no-member

class ItemHistoryModel(Item):

    __tablename__ = 'item_history'

    historyId = databaseHandler.Column(databaseHandler.Integer, primary_key = True)
```

I have a class method in both files that is supposed to help me get a list of items a restaurant sells by passing in the `restaurantId` as parameter

```
@classmethod
def findItemsByRestaurant(cls, param):
    return cls.query.filter_by(restaurantId = param)
```

However, anytime I execute this method it returns a query string in the resultset instead of a list of items. Here is a sample resultset:

```
SELECT item_history.`itemName` AS `item_history_itemName`, item_history.price AS item_history_price, item_history.`itemImage` AS `item_history_itemImage`, item_history.`historyId` AS `item_history_historyId` 
FROM item_history 
WHERE false = 1
```

Somehow, SQLAlchemy makes my parameter `false` and assigns a value of `1` to it meanwhile the actual ID of the restaurant is `10`. What am I doing wrong?

This is the `databaseHandler.py` file:

```
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

databaseHandler = SQLAlchemy()
```

Comment: Query’s are not the objects, to get the objects use `.all()` or `.first()`

Comment: I added .all() and it worked! Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The [Query object](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/query.html) has a number of API methods for getting pythonic objects rather than amending the query:

- get
- all
- from_statement
- first
- one_or_none
- one
- scalar (as_scalar to be depreciated)
- count